# control parallel tests with nose

Tags: python, nose

I'm trying to follow the nose documentation regarding multiprocessing: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/multiprocess.html.  I know there is a bug in 1.3.0 so i downgraded to 1.1.0.

I have a runner that loads many tests. Within those tests I have one test suite I do not want to run in parallel. I actually want to only run this suite consecutively.  I can't figure out which directive I need to give the test suite to enforce this.  I think it can be done but not 100% sure. If I understand correctly I should be able to use the _multiprocess_shared_ = True but it is not working

```
import unittest
import time

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    _multiprocess_shared_ = True
    def setUp(self):
        print "set up called"
    def test_1(self):
        print "test1"
        time.sleep(4)
    def test_2(self):
        print "test2"
    def test_3(self):
        print 'test3'
```

The output is this

```
set up called
test1
set up called
test2
set up called
test3
test2...ok
test3...ok
test1...ok
```

I was hoping it was this

```
setup called
test1
test1...ok
setup called
test2
test2...0k
setup called
test3
test3...ok
```

Comment: What happens *without* `_multiprocessing_shared_ = True`? AFAIK from the documentation setting that attribute tells nose to *do* use multiple workers for the tests. I don't see how(and why) you want to share the tests on more test runners but you want to run them sequentially...

Comment: Same behavior without.  For more context I'm calling many tests with nosetests --processes=5 <list of test suites>.  The obvious, hacky way IMO, would be to omit this suite and run in after/before the others with nosetests --processes=1

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this same question right now.

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing shared applies to class/module level fixtures not test level which is what setUp() does.
Try adding a setUpClass() method instead and it should be called in that manner.